# What is $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}(1-\alpha(t))(1-\beta(t))\beta(t)^{n-1}dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $\alpha(t)=\frac{e^{t}-1}{q^{-1}e^t-1}$ and $\beta(t)=\frac{e^t-1}{e^t-q}$, where $q\in(0,1)$.

What is $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}(1-\alpha(t))(1-\beta(t))\beta(t)^{n-1}dt$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variable $e^t=x$. Then your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-t}(1-\alpha(t))(1-\beta(t))\beta(t)^{n-1}dt=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{x-1}{q^{-1} x-1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x-1}{ x-q}\right)\left(\frac{x-1}{ x-q}\right)^{n-1}
$$
$$
=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2(x-q)^{n+1}}(x-q-qx+q)(1-q)(x-1)^{n-1}
$$
$$
=(1-q)^2\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x(x-q)^{n+1}}(x-1)^{n-1}\ .
$$
Expanding via the binomial theorem
$$
=(1-q)^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}(-1)^{n-1-k}\int_1^\infty \frac{dx\ x^{k-1}}{(x-q)^{n+1}}\ .
$$
Setting now $x-q=z$, we have
$$
=(1-q)^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}(-1)^{n-1-k}\int_{1-q}^\infty dz(q+z)^{k-1}z^{-n-1}\ .
$$
The integral is identified with an incomplete Beta function. Hence
$$
=\boxed{(1-q)^2 \sum _{k=0}^{n-1}  \binom{n-1}{k} q^{k-n-1} \mathrm{B}_{\frac{q}{q-1}}(-k+n+1,k)\ ,}
$$
for $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete answer.

Maybe exist a pattern to find formula for general solution.

Using  **CAS** like **Mathematica**.

Let's try for arbitrary `n`. Solution be found by Laplace Transform for `s=1`.

```
A[t_] := (Exp[t] - 1)/(q^(-1)*Exp[t] - 1);
B[t_] := (Exp[t] - 1)/(Exp[t] - q);
f[n_] := (1 - A[t])*(1 - B[t])*B[t]^(n - 1) // FullSimplify // ExpandAll;

n = 0;(* Here you can change *)

Limit[Assuming[0 < q < 1, LaplaceTransform[f[n], t, s]], s -> 1, 
Assumptions -> 0 < q < 1] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify // Expand
```

for $n=0$
$$\frac{\log (1-q)}{q}-\log (1-q)$$

for $n=1$
$$\frac{\log (1-q)}{q^2}+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2 \log (1-q)}{q}+\log (1-q)-1$$

for $n=2$
$$\frac{\log (1-q)}{q^3}+\frac{1}{q^2}-\frac{2 \log (1-q)}{q^2}-\frac{3}{2 q}+\frac{\log
   (1-q)}{q}+\frac{1}{2}$$

for $n=3$
$$\frac{\log (1-q)}{q^4}+\frac{1}{q^3}-\frac{2 \log (1-q)}{q^3}-\frac{3}{2 q^2}+\frac{\log
   (1-q)}{q^2}+\frac{1}{3 q}+\frac{1}{6}$$